# how to get weibo (weibo.com) Consumer and secret key?

Tags: iphone, oauth, social-networking, weibo, sinaweibo

how can i get consumer key and secret key (for oauth type) for a china website www.weibo.com

I want to integrate this website features in iOS app.

Thanks,

Comment: Although I find this link but unable to get how to register app for key.. http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Oauth/en

Answer (score 3):

the first step ,you should create your app at this link `http://open.weibo.com/apps`,then you will get the secret

Comment: Hi Welsonla, Any tutorial or working source code that show how to authenticate and how to post text/comment on weibo.com

Answer (score 3):

There's a good walkthrough for the process of getting a developer key here:
http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/82_Socialize_Setup/005_Opening_External_Applications/Sina_Weibo

Just bear in mind that you'll want to specify what type of application you're building in the drop down menus in step 8.

Also, the SDK has now been upgraded to 2.0 to use oAuth2, though this isn't yet reflected in the English language documentation.